# No module named 'pm4py'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, cmd, import, anaconda

I want to use 'pm4py' but while import:

`from pm4py.objects.log.importer.xes import factory as xes_import_factory`

I got error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pm4py`

I use Visual Studio Code on Windows. When I use `pip install pm4py` from it's terminal(or cmd) I got error like:

```
Building wheel for cvxopt (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

But when i use same line `pip install pm4py` in Anaconda Prompt then it returns that all Requirements are already satisfied (I think I already installed this package). I even found the folder named 'pm4py' in `anaconda\lib\site-packages`.

pm4py also doesn't appear on the `pip list` in cmd (and i think it should?).

I've been searching the internet for several hours and can't find a solution. What can I do to use `import pm4py`?

Comment: It looks like you have 2 different Python installations, on in VS Code and one in Anaconda. The module you want is installed in the Anaconda installation but not in the VS Code installation. Can't help you with the `pip` error message because you left out the cause of the error. Start by running `pip --version` in all your environments (VS Code, Windows cmd, Anaconda). This will very likely show you what is happening. When you have a handle on it, explicitly call `...\Python3x\Scripts\pip.exe` to be sure of getting your install going where it should go.

Comment: Ok so in cmd and VSC i got: 
`pip 20.0.2 from c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)`
and on my anaconda Prompt:
`pip 19.2.3 from C:\...\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip <python3.7>`

Comment: And in Anaconda?

Comment: And how can i show you error message. Just copy here? Its pretty huge. 
(I gave you anaconda pip in the message above).

Comment: Ok, after your advice i checked `Python\lib\site-packages` and `anaconda\lib\site-packages` and there were pm4py folders in python while they were not in anaconda. And I feel like i did bad thing (like a barbarian) cause i just copied this folders from anaconda folder into python folder. But it seems work. In cmd `pip list` now pm4py is showing up. And in VSC `import pm4py` also works. But I feel bad about how I did it. If it can cause any problems later and you have any nicer solution I would be grateful.

Comment: I suggest you post a new question along the lines of *how do I keep my VSCode installs in sync with my Anaconda installs?* I don't use either so I'm no real help to you there.

Comment: VS Code is probably not configured to use your Conda environments. Be careful when using pip inside of a Conda environment, see https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/.

Answer (score 1):

Solved for jupyter notebook projects: by executing conda install -c conda-forge ciso8601 then pip install pm4py

Answer (score -3):

I encountered the same issue and guess this has been depreciated as development ceased.

Comment: Consider adding some investigation to support your guess.